# Not loading from pickled file

Tags: python, pickle

I'm running Python 3.5 on macOS Sierra. I have a system where I store instances of a class as a list in a file (using `dill`) and then unpickle them to perform operations, add to them, delete them, etc. The problem is that when I set the `localData` list (the list of loaded classes) to the data loaded from the file, I can't interact with it.

**Here's my code:**

```
import dill as pickle


...


dataFileLocation = "./data.ehd"
localData = []


class eventClass:
    def __init__(self, name, items, organisers):
        self.name       =   name
        self.items      =   items
        self.organisers =   organisers
        loadData()
        self.id         =   len(localData)

def loadData():
    try:
        dataFile            =   open(dataFileLocation, "rb")
        localData           =   pickle.load(dataFile)
        return localData
    except (IOError, EOFError):
        return False


def newEvent(name, items, organisers):
    loadData()
    localData.append(eventClass(name, items, organisers))
    with open(dataFileLocation, "wb+") as dataFile:
        pickle.dump(localData, dataFile)


...


def getInfo(name):
    loadData()
    for event in localData:
        if event.name == name:
            organisers      =   ""
            for organiser in event.organisers:
                organisers  =   (organisers + ", " + str(organiser))
            items = ""
            for item in event.items:
                items       =   (items + ", " + str(item))
            items           =   items[2:]
            organisers      =   organisers[2:]
            print("Name:        " + str(event.name))
            print("Internal ID: " + str(event.id))
            print("Items:       " + items)
            print("Organisers:  " + organisers)


def prompt():
    task = input("EventHorizon >")
    execute(task)
    prompt()


def execute(task):
    task                    =   task.lower().split(" ")
    if task[0] == ("newevent"):
        name                =   task[1]
        items               =   task[2].split(":")
        organisers          =   task[3].split(":")
        newEvent(name, items, organisers)
    elif task[0] == ("dropevent"):
        name                =   task[1]
        dropEvent(name)
    elif task[0] == ("getinfo"):
        name                =   task[1]
        getInfo(name)
    elif task[0] == ("quit") or task[0] == ("exit"):
        quit()
    elif task[0] == ("loaddata"):
        loadData()




loadData()
prompt()
```

**Here's what I'm doing (starting with a blank data.ehd):**

```
bash-3.2$ python3 main.py
EventHorizon >newEvent myEvent myItem myOrganiser
EventHorizon >newEvent myEvent2 myItem2 myOrganiser2
EventHorizon >getInfo myEvent
Name:           myevent
Internal ID:    0
Items:          myitem
Organisers:     myorganiser
EventHorizon >getInfo myEvent2
Name:           myevent2
Internal ID:    1
Items:          myitem2
Organisers:     myorganiser2
EventHorizon >exit
bash-3.2$ python3 main.py
EventHorizon >loadData
EventHorizon >getInfo myEvent
EventHorizon >getInfo myEvent2
```

There is no output showing the attributes of the event. I have also tested this starting with a `data.ehd` file that **does** contain data (writing to it works fine).

Why is this occurring?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I bet it has something to do with the fact that the return value of `loadData` is being discarded because you never assign it to anything... `localData` is a local variable in `loadData` and won't affect `localData` in other scopes...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using `localData = pickle.load(dataFile)` to do that - `return localData` was just for testing purposes and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Yes, but that only affects the local variable in `loadData`. Indeed, you *should* be returning `localData`. When you call `loadData()` it doesn't do anything because you simply discard the object you have loaded because you don't assign the return value to anything.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! Do you mind if I post that as an answer?

Comment: Go ahead, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga, this problem has been solved!

The problem was that the `localData` variable inside `loadData` was only local and so the `localData` in the main code was not updated.

This was fixed by modifying `loadData` at the start to define `localData` as global. The modified `loadData` is:

```
def loadData():
    global localData
    try:
        dataFile            =   open(dataFileLocation, "rb")
        localData           =   pickle.load(dataFile)
    except (IOError, EOFError):
        return False
```